# Optimize performance for queries on recent rows of a large table

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have a large table:

```
CREATE TABLE "orders" (
"id" serial NOT NULL,
"person_id" int4,
"created" int4,
CONSTRAINT "orders_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

90% of all requests are about orders from the last 2-3 days by a `person_id`, like:

```
select * from orders
where person_id = 1
and created >= extract(epoch from current_timestamp)::int - 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;
```

How can I improve performance?

I know about [Partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html), but what about existing rows? And it looks like I need to create `INHERITS` tables manually every 2-3 days.

Comment: Do you know about [Indexing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-intro.html)?

Comment: yes, sure, i already have index (person_id, created)

Comment: What's wrong with just creating an index on `created`? I don't see how partitioning would help here. It would serve as an inefficient index. So just create the index in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [**partial, multicolumn index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html) on `(person_id, created)` with a pseudo-`IMMUTABLE` condition would help (a lot). Needs to be recreated from time to time to keep performance up.

*Note, if your table is not very big, you can largely simplify and use a plain multicolumn index.

Or consider [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) in Postgres 12 or later (where the feature finally matured).*

A primitive **function** provides a constant point in time, 3 or more days back (represented by a unix epoch in your case):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_orders_idx_start()
  RETURNS int LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE COST 1 AS
'SELECT 1387497600';
```

`PARALLEL SAFE` only for Postgres 10 or later.
`1387497600` being the result of:

```sql
SELECT extract(epoch from now())::integer - 259200;
-- 259200 being the result of 60 * 60 * 24 * 3
```

Base your **partial index** on this pseudo-`IMMUTABLE` condition:

```sql
CREATE INDEX orders_created_recent_idx ON orders (person_id, created)
WHERE created >= f_orders_idx_start();
```

Base your **query** on the same condition:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   orders
WHERE  person_id = 1
AND    created >= f_orders_idx_start()  -- match partial idx condition
AND    created >= extract(epoch from now())::integer - 259200;  -- actual condition
```

The line `AND created >= f_orders_idx_start()` seems redundant, but is instrumental to convince Postgres to use the partial index.

A **function to recreate function and index** from time to time. Possibly with a cron-job every night:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_orders_reindex_partial()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   -- 3 days back, starting at 00:00
   _start int := extract(epoch from now()::date -3)::int;
BEGIN       
   IF _start = f_orders_idx_start() THEN
      -- do nothing, nothing changes.
   ELSE
      DROP INDEX IF EXISTS orders_created_recent_idx;
      -- Recreate IMMUTABLE function
      EXECUTE format('
         CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_orders_idx_start()
           RETURNS int LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE COST 1 AS
         $$SELECT %s $$'
       , _start
      );
      -- Recreate partial index
      CREATE INDEX orders_created_recent_idx ON orders (person_id, created)
      WHERE created >= f_orders_idx_start();
   END IF;    
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, to rebase your index, call (ideally with little or no concurrent load):

```sql
SELECT f_orders_reindex_partial();  -- that's all
```

If you cannot afford dropping and recreating the index due to concurrent load, consider `REINDEX CONCURRENTLY` in Postgres 12 or later. It's dead simple:

```sql
REINDEX INDEX orders_created_recent_idx;
```

**All queries continue to work, even if you never call this function.** Performance slowly deteriorates over time with the growing partial index.

I am using this regime successfully with a couple of big tables and similar requirements. *Very fast.*

For Postgres 9.2 or later, and if your table has only few, small columns, and if the table is not heavily written, it might pay to make that a [**covering index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html):

```sql
CREATE INDEX orders_created_recent_idx ON orders (person_id, created, id)
WHERE created >= f_orders_idx_start();
```

In Postgres 11 or later, you might want to use [`INCLUDE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) instead:

```sql
CREATE INDEX orders_created_recent_idx ON orders (person_id, created) INCLUDE (id)
WHERE created >= f_orders_idx_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesstion:-

It may help you. 
Since the table size is growing, your query performance  going to be decreased gradually. Better maintain 3-5 days ( **If you are very sure about going to access only 2-3 days** ) records and periodically migrate the old records to backup table.

Comment: yeah, thanks. I considered this option, but it requires quite a bit of changes, because 10% request must go into backup tables.

Comment: I thought that there is an easier way than split table malualy and then maintain it manualy or by script every 2-5 days.

Comment: If you are not dependent on old records , fairly  you can have backup table with same structure and use db_link to migrate the data's easily.  then make it migrate operation as batch process ( automation)