# Postgres using partial index on enum type for equality condition but not for inequality

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes, inequality, query-planner

Using PostgreSQL 9.6.9, I have:

- a custom SQL enum type with 3 levels used in a column of some
  table xy.
- a composite partial index on the highest level (level3) of this enum on table xy.
- a lot of dummy data (more than 200000 rows)

And using `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` in the console, I see that:

```
SELECT ... FROM xy WHERE ... AND custom_type = 'level3' <--- Index Scan used
```

but:

```
SELECT ... FROM xy WHERE ... AND custom_type > 'level2' <--- Index Scan NOT used
```

The queries are exactly the same, except for the inequality/equality condition.

Is the database planner not able to see that above level2 there can only be level3 and thus it could use the partial index ?

Why did Postgres not optimize this properly ... this seems like some simple logic thing.

Comment: I repeat my conclusion here: after updating all table stats using `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` it never uses the partial index, so my guess is that as the partial index was newer it was more up-to-date than the other index I had. But the thing about partial indexes being very precise and the redundant conditions is also interesting.

Comment: I also think my random data does not reflect the potential real-world ratio of the enum values for this table, so I may reconsider this aswell and analyze the table again to see if this changes index usage.

Comment: I added more info to my answer addressing your comments.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That answer is like a small article, I hope it will be useful for other people too

Comment: That's the idea. Pretty much generally here. :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Let's say that on SO you are the John Skeet of Postgres

Comment: Jon is going to feel flattered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Generally

Postgres only uses an index (or bitmap index) scan if it estimates it to be faster overall. An inequality condition typically returns (many) more rows than an equality condition. So the query planner is likely to switch to a sequential scan if table statistics and cost setting suggest this might be faster. Using an index add overhead and typically only improves performance when a *small* percentage of rows is fetched from the table. Something like 5 % or less, varies a lot with details.

Are you sure table statistics are up to date? Did you run `ANALYZE` on the table? See:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

To test, whether the index ***can*** be used, disable sequential scans in a test session (for debugging only!):

```
 SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

Then run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` again.

#### Partial index

Postgres only considers partial indexes if `WHERE` conditions are met in the query pretty much *exactly*. There is no advanced logic trying to analyze expressions (since that could quickly get out of hand and add overhead to the majority of queries that do not profit from the partial index).

If you have a partial index with the condition `WHERE custom_type = 'level3'` a query with the condition `WHERE custom_type > 'level2'` is not even considered. The simple solution is to add the condition of the partial index to your query (redundantly). Like:

```
SELECT ... FROM xy WHERE ... AND custom_type > 'level2'
AND custom_type = 'level3';  -- redundant, but makes Postgres consider partial index
```

Just be careful when trying to be smart: if you later extend your `enum` type, the query may be broken.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL does not use a partial index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030354/postgresql-does-not-use-a-partial-index/26031289#26031289)
- [Optimize performance for queries on recent rows of a large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738000/optimize-performance-for-queries-on-recent-rows-of-a-large-table/20749825#20749825)

#### Indexes and statistics

Note two things:

There are separate per-column statistics for a partial index that involves functional expressions, but not with only plain column references.

Creating an index does not trigger an `ANALYZE` on the underlying table (or for itself) automatically. But basic statistics like the row count are updated in `pg_class`.

- [Kaminari is slow with COUNT(*) on a huge table in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839330/kaminari-is-slow-with-count-on-a-huge-table-in-postgres/21839499#21839499)
- [PostgreSQL partial index unused when created on a table with existing data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99323/postgresql-partial-index-unused-when-created-on-a-table-with-existing-data/99324#99324)
- [Inconsistent statistics on jsonb column with btree index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167525/inconsistent-statistics-on-jsonb-column-with-btree-index/167652#167652)
- [GIN index not used when adding order clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113132/gin-index-not-used-when-adding-order-clause/114219#114219)
- [Optimizing slow performance of simple SELECT query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187923/optimizing-slow-performance-of-simple-select-query/187981#187981)

Comment: I have used `SET enable_seqscan = OFF` but this is not the issue here. The issue is that the planner does not seem to know that only `level3` exists above `level2` as it does use the index in the `= 'level3'` case with same data. I suppose the planner does not have this simple logic built-in.

Comment: *Do* you see index scans with `enable_seqscan = OFF`? And are table statistics up to date?

Comment: @KamilG. those enums are ordered, this is why inequality conditions work.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy I don't think it has any effect on the index search (the fact that it's an enum which is ordered vs your partial index).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, ok so after updating all table stats using `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` it never uses the partial index, so my guess is that as the partial index was newer it was more up-to-date than that other index I had. Also thank you for all your answers, this makes using Postgres a bit easier.