# How to create index on records for last 90 days in Postgres Making now() immutable

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have a case where due to speed issues I only want to create the index on records for last 90 days.

When I try to create index like this:

```
create index if not exists idx_d1_section_learner_partial_date_modified
    on instruct.d1_section_learner (audit_modified_datetime)
    where (audit_modified_datetime >= '2019-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp);
```

It works, but I wanted to keep this dynamic so I tried this:

```
create index if not exists idx_d1_section_learner_partial_date_modified
    on instruct.d1_section_learner (audit_modified_datetime)
    where (audit_modified_datetime >= now() - interval '90 days'::timestamp);
```

It gives error:

> ERROR: functions in index predicate must be marked IMMUTABLE

I know that is happening because of current timestamp. Because it's not constant in transaction. Is there a way I can do this avoiding that?

Or maybe can I mark `current_timestamp` as immutable?

Comment: Think about what your are trying to do there: the complete index would need to change every millisecond, because the interval you are defining is constantly changing. It sounds as if you actually want to [partition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) your table

Comment: And note, that ```now()``` IS constant inside one transaction (since you always get the start of the transaction). The same is true for ```CURRENT_TIMESTAMP```.

Comment: @Islingre then why am i getting err ?

Comment: As the horse already explained, functions with changing values cannot be allowed. An index is usually made for much longer than just the transaction that creates it. So you need functions that are ```IMMUTABLE```, meaning for the same input they will ALWAYS produce the same output. ```now()``` is only ```STABLE```. For more information, you might have a look into the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html

Comment: Even if you were able to create the second index, what do you think a query to use it would look like?  I agree that partitioning is really what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an immutable `now()` function (which wouldn't work!) use a pseudo-immutable function returning a `timestamp` constant, and base your partial index on it - as well as your queries that are supposed to use it.

Also, you don't *have to* update the index every day. The index can hold a couple of outdated rows, that's hardly relevant. You just add an *exact* condition to your queries *additionally*. Performance deteriorates *slowly* over time as more rows are added. It's enough to recreate function and index from time to time. Can be every week at times with the lowest DB load.

It just so happens that I posted a **complete solution** for the case *6 years ago*:

- [Optimize performance for queries on recent rows of a large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738000/optimize-performance-for-queries-on-recent-rows-of-a-large-table/20749825#20749825)

Updated it a bit to reflect recent developments.

Aside: `now()` returns `timestamptz`, not `timestamp`. `LOCALTIMESTAMP` would be a better fit. But don't go there.